# tinymce 4 - set css file only if wanted (else, do nothing)

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm working with tinyMCE 4 and want to load a specific css only on a specific page.

I know it is possible to add `content_css: "/path/to/my/file.css" on init function (and it works well).

But since I want it only on a aspecific page I want to add it dynamically.

I've tried using `tinymce.DOM.loadCSS()` instructions but it does not work. See the doc :
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.loadCSS

I've alos tried `tinymce.get('someid').dom.loadCSS('somepath/some.css');` but I get back the following : *error : TypeError: tinyMCE.get(...) is undefined*

I'll appreciate some help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to get this work is to add a setup function to the init function :

```js
tinymce.init({
// include newsletter css file
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('PreInit', function(e) {
        if(typeof mycsspath !== "undefined") {
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.loadCSS(mycsspath);
        }
    });
},
// other config options there
// ...
});
```